# How to connect to a socket.io server from a Cocos2d-x game?

Tags: cocos2d-x

The question can also be asked more specifically as; How do I connect to a socket.io server with C++ from a mobile game?

I am aware of Boost (and Socket.io C++ client libraries using Boost) but compiling them for iOS and Android is beyond me. So what do you guys recommend?

Comment: Just found this, should've searched more before asking. https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/blob/v3/cocos/network/SocketIO.cpp